# How to detect break signal in LIN?

Tags: stm32, uart

I am going to implement LIN protocol using STM32 UART peripheral. I want to detect break signal of LIN header message. How can I detect break signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you gave no information about your microcontroller, I will use STM32F103 (Blue pill/Nucleo MCU) as an example. Other STM32 should have something similar.

[image]

There is a dedicated line break flag in the status register. As you can see, it also mentions a dedicated line break interrupt, if you need it.